How to Build a PSD-Based Image Customization System in Node.js?
I’m working on a Node.js project and need help with the following:

Allow users to upload a PSD template.

Accept JSON data as input.

Replace template elements (like text and images) with data from the JSON.

Generate a new customized image based on the template and input data.


I’m looking for recommendations on libraries/tools for:

Reading and modifying PSD files.

Efficient image processing in Node.js.

Handling high-resolution images for production use.


So far, I’ve explored:

psd.js for PSD parsing, but it seems limited in terms of editing.

sharp for image processing, though not specific to PSD files.


Does anyone have experience implementing something like this? Any advice on approaches, best practices, or alternative libraries would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
I haven’t implemented anything yet, as I’m unsure about the best libraries or approach to use. I’m looking for guidance on where to start, especially for parsing and editing PSD files with JSON data in Node.js.

how to make a photo editor? that is an entire engineering project. that's way out of scope for Stack Overflow. [ask], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

@burninghat (1) Which part of those 4 steps are you stuck at? Surely "upload a user file into my page" is a basic tutorial search. Step 4 needs a plan... Was the idea to send it back to Photoshop (for image generation) or did you want to render a PSD in website (without Photoshop first returning an image from edited PSD)? (2) Have you worked with bytes before (can read/write/search data inside an array)? Not clear how complicated the PSD templates (num of layers and items). If it's just one image and one text box, maybe just hard code those editing byte positions into some JS function?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
